# Manually Update Angular-UI UI-Sortable Items

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Essentially, I would like users to be able to drag and drop an item or click up/down arrows to move an item in the list.

Is there a good way to update the items' indexes that plays nice with ui-sortable/angular-ui?

Thanks.

## update

we were able to solve this by adding a function in our controller that would remove the item from the array and add it back in one index greater or lesser than its original position. Here is a sloppy example:

```
$scope.upDown = function(oldIndex, newIndex) {
    var item = $scope.list[oldIndex];
    $scope.list.splice(oldIndex,1);
    $scope.list.splice(newIndex,0,item);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/69auq/1/

you would need to add a check if it was the first or last elem in the array to disable up or down accordingly.

Comment: The moment the sort has stopped, which you can capture, the items on your scope will be in their new order.  Push them, or the their ids to a service.

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we were able to solve this by adding a function in our controller that would remove the item from the array and add it back in one index greater or lesser than its original position. Here is a sloppy example:

```
$scope.upDown = function(oldIndex, newIndex) {
    var item = $scope.list[oldIndex];
    $scope.list.splice(oldIndex,1);
    $scope.list.splice(newIndex,0,item);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/69auq/1/

you would need to add a check if it was the first or last elem in the array to disable up or down accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As with everything AngularJS, the answer is to ["think in Angular, not jQuery"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).

[This CodePen](http://codepen.io/SimeonC/pen/AJIyC) does a good job illustrating how to do it. Basically, you've got a scoped temp object for the dragging around, which you then push into the ng-repeat's bound array. I can't take credit for it (not my creation), but Google led me to it fairly quickly. The CodePen doesn't use any external dependencies, but as you can see, it means a bit more work than using something like [Angular-UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/).

Here's [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g/hKYWr/) showing the same concept, but with Angular-UI dependency. The advantage of using angular-ui is that your bound data array needs only to be invoked as such:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui']);

myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
});
```

This means less work on your part, since it's already been figured out. AngularJS does a good job of playing nicely with jQuery, so this shouldn't dictate a huge shift in development approach from jQuery UI, depending on your use case.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question. I am using angular-ui which provides the drag and drop functionality. I also need to be able to move a single item up/down 1 index in the array with out dragging and dropping.

Comment: I guess I'm confused why you're trying to manipulate the list, which is already scoped, by invoking a function when the functionality is included by nature of manipulating the scoped data array. Also, I apparently missed your 'ui' dependency. Thanks for posting back your working solution.